# 403 (Forbidden). Слетают стили и скрипты в админке Битрикс

Tags: javascript, php, css, битрикс, стилизация

Зашел на страницу Email рассылок админки битрикса

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В инструментах разработчика выводит следующие ошибки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как устранить эти ошибки и добиться правильного отображения таблицы рассылок в админке, так чтобы не удалить типы инфоблоков, инфоблоки и элементы инфоблоков?

P.S. Я использую OpneServer

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В каких настройках есть ошибка OpenServer-а?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S. Можно ли просто скопировать папку bitrix из сайта с работающей админкой, так чтобы не затерлись типы инфоблоков, инфоблоки и элементы инфоблоков?

1. Конфиг Apache (C:\OpenServer\modules\http\Apache_2.4-PHP_7.0-7.1\conf\httpd.conf) имеет вид - http://d.zaix.ru/yusZ.txt, полсе редактирования - http://d.zaix.ru/yutC.txt (убрал LocationMatch).
2. Пытался также менять право доступа в windows через свойства

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорей всего настройки локального веб сервера. Похожий тикет https://qna.habr.com/q/700449

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: @Salavey на приведенной Вами странице в ответе написано, что надо было кое-что убрать из конфига apache. Конфиг Apache - это файл .htaccess или какой-то другой файл?

Comment: @Salavey где находится конфиг apache в Windows?

Comment: @Salavey обновил вопрос. Очень нужно, помогите.

Comment: @vladwebsearch вы же на OpenServer грузите сайт. У него Apache вы можете найти нажав на флаг -> Дополнительно -> Конфигурация. Только не помню, что бы когда либо лазил в Apache, только в PHP лазил помню, так как Битрикс же особенный, ему подавай особые настройки))

Comment: Всем спасибо. Действительно, проблема была в том, что правил не тот конфиг (надо было выбрать из меню опенсервера)

Comment: как указал @ЕвгенийЛи. Необходимо было редактировать конфиг - `C:\OpenServer\userdata\config\Apache_2.4-PHP_7.0-7.1_server.conf`.

Answer (score 0):

Я кажется нашёл решение если используется связка apache + nginx, находим конфиг файл для Nginx и комментируем следующую строку:

```
location ~* /\.(?!well-known/) {
    deny all;
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, уточните прямо в тексте ответа (нажав [edit]), которую из пяти приведённых вами строк вы предлагаете закомментировать.

Comment: наверное всю строку имеется ввиду